# Getting NoResponseException while creating MultiUserChat

Tags: android, exception, smack

I'm trying to create a multiuser chat with XMPP Smack Api(4.1.4). I've established a login connection using,

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configBuilder.setResource(RESOURCE);
    configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
    configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
    XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                connection.connect();
                if(connection != null) {
                PingManager mPingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                mPingManager.setDefaultPingInterval(1000 * 50);
                mPingManager.setPingInterval(1000 * 50);
                connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(1000 * 50);
                mPingManager.registerPingFailedListener(new PingFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void pingFailed() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("PING", "ping failed");
                    // AGain Reconnecting code here..
            }
        });
    }
            } catch (IOException | SmackException | XMPPException e) {
                Log.d(LOCAL_TAG, "connectConnection  exc: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
```

and it gets connected sucessfully. After connecting, i'm trying to create a group chat using,

```
    try {
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("App_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userJid = userJidAddress(with local ip);
        String userName =  "Test5";
        Log.d(LOCAL_TAG, "createGroupChat  jid: "+userJid+" -- connection.getServiceName(): "+connection.getServiceName());

        MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(userJid);

        muc.create("InstantRoom");

        Log.d(LOCAL_TAG, "createGroupChat  -- Group CEATED Successfully ");
        Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

        List<FormField> fields = form.getFields();
        Log.d(LOCAL_TAG, "createGroupChat  -- fields.size(): "+fields.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.get(i);
            if (!FormField.Type.hidden.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }

        List owners = new ArrayList();
        owners.add("test5"+connection.getServiceName());
        owners.add("test7"); //Another user
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
        muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
        muc.join("InstantRoom");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(LOCAL_TAG, "createGroupChat --  Exception: "+e.toString());
    }
```

But While creating the group, i get an Exception as

```
    "org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 50000ms (~50s). Used filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): test5@172.21.4.199/instantroom, StanzaTypeFilter: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence)."
```

If i increase the PingIntervals and PacketReplyTimeout milliseconds, then i get a message as

**"Thread[5,tid=4403,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb8e933a8,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3".**

without that exception and app set to force close automatically. Hope so, I'm getting the exception at muc.create("InstantRoom") line, because i couldn't get the log after that line. 
Can anyone help me by figure out what i'm doing wrong and why i'm getting this error and how to proceed after this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, post your code (with muc.create() ) ;)

Comment: @MrPk Hi  thanks for your response. i have edited my code please check it and give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this 2 lines are wrong

```
 MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(userJid);

        muc.create("InstantRoom");
```

when you get a MUC, you have to get a NAME (so the manager can tell you if already exist).

indeed, when you create a muc, you'll have to enter an username.

So

```
String myMUCName = "InstantRoom";
String myMUCService = "conference.myServer";
String myMUCfullName = myMUCName + "@" + myMUCService;
MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(myMUCfullName);
muc.create(userName);
```

*(if this will not solve your problem just tell me after assure yourself that the service it's already registered on Server - maybe you'll have extra issue on Form)*

Comment: Hi.. Thank you so much for your sugestion. This solves that error. But instead of using "conference.myServer" as myMUCService, i used "conference.(my local ip)", since i got server nor found error. But After fixing this, i got another exception as "org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: forbidden - auth". I've  added the members as owners.add("test5"); //Own user
owners.add("test7"); //Another user and hope so i'm getting the exception at "muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);" line. Because,i couldn't get the log if i put below that code.Plz suggest me any idea.

Comment: Hi.. I've fixed that exception by changing  "muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);" code to "muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(DataForm.Type.submit));". After changing like this, i didn't get any exception and finally got "Group Joined" log as printed. But i do know how my selected users for the group gets added. I'm not sure that doing right. Plz suggest me to how to proceed.

Comment: Please accept the answer then open a new one (feel free to link me the new question), too much things to explain for a comment. Of course 'myserver' was a placehilder, good job =)

Comment: sorry for the delay